# make[2]: *** [o.le-v7-g/ApplicationName] make[1]: *** [debug] make: *** [Device-Debug]

Tags: compilation, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to build blackberry 10 cascades application. When I am deploying the code to my device, I am getting below errors. Can you please help?

```
make[2]: *** [o.le-v7-g/ApplicationName] Error 1 ApplicationName C/C++ Problem
make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2 ApplicationName C/C++ Problem
make: *** [Device-Debug] Error 2 ApplicationName C/C++ Problem
```

.pro file looks like this

```
APP_NAME = ApplicationName

CONFIG += qt warn_on cascades10

include(config.pri)
LIBS += -lbbdata
LIBS += -lbb
```

Main.cpp file content is below

```
#include "applicationui.hpp"
#include "sqlconnect.hpp"

#include <bb/cascades/Application>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

#include <Qt/qdeclarativedebug.h>

using namespace bb::cascades;

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Application app(argc, argv);

    // Create the Application UI object, this is where the main.qml file
    // is loaded and the application scene is set.
    ApplicationUI appui;

    // Enter the application main event loop.
    return Application::exec();
}
```

Comment: Clean project, that helps sometimes. Otherwise why are you even touching main.cpp? Do what you need to in applicationui.cpp

Comment: I was looking at couple of samples to see how main.cpp looks and it varied. So wanted to take main.cpp that is more appropriate for application such as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into couple of sites and I then I found from the build logs that 
LIBS += -lbbsystem. Initially I wasn't sure how to read the logs but with this compilation error, I learnt it.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/make-2-o-le-v7-g-ApplicationName-make-1-debug-make-Device-Debug/m-p/3010212#M68425 has details